# Looking for a permissive and active cross-platform image processing library in C/C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, cross-platform

I'm looking a cross-platform image processing library in C/C++ which is under active development. One more requirement: No GPL license.

Some references:

[Fast Cross-Platform C/C++ Image Processing Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796364/fast-cross-platform-c-c-image-processing-libraries)

[Cross-platform drawing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200727/cross-platform-drawing-library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for some courses in university. Played quite well.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your questions what you mean image processing, what algorithms are you interested in

Check [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) which is multi-threaded toolkit derived from ImageMagick, available under X11-style license.

AMD released [Framewave](http://framewave.sourceforge.net/) which provides image processing functionality, under Apache v2.0 license.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ImageStack](http://code.google.com/p/imagestack/) for a few projects, and it is under active development. You can use it as a command-line tool, or as a library.